# Separately Animating Multiple Segments That Belong to One Layer: Adobe Illustrator and After Effects

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, stroke, adobe-after-effects

I am using Adobe Illustrator and Adobe After Effects.
I want to animate an SVG triangle. I want the Hypotenuse to "swing out" from the bottom leg (go from 0 deg to 45deg). I can do this by 1), making each triangle segment its own layer, 2) setting an anchor point at the bottom left vertex (see the graph), and then 3), going into after effects and change the rotation of the hypotenuse line segment. The problem is that the line segments do not join properly. As you can see the vertices are not filled in. I can fix this by joining the the segments, but then all the segments become one layer, and I cannot animate the hypotenuse swinging.

My question is: is there a way to animate the hypotenuse segment swinging out, while making sure the vertices are joined properly? Here is a photo for reference.
[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Video editing questions are off-topic here. Probably better suited to Video Production Stack Exchange. You can flag your question and ask the moderators to migrate it for you if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Round line ends fit in different angles:

[image]

If you have a closed triangle you can move one of its anchor points. The lines follow. Round corners should be used for non-peaky look.

[image]

Grey and green triangles were originally equal. The top corner anchor point of the green triangle is moved upwards.

Scaling (=dragging the top side of the bounding box) does the same. Prevent Stroke width scaling in the preferences!

[image]

ADD due a comment:

You can well have a closed triangle. Shrink it vertically from full height to a line and then horizontally from full width to a single point. Reverse the animation frame sequence to get a video which presents the growth from a single point to the full triangle.

[image]

Comment: The issue is I also want to use a trim path animation to have the base expand from the  bottom left vertex to the bottom right vertex. This leads me to conclude I must treat each segment as it’s own later, but the I do not think I will be able to round join the vertices.

Comment: I guess I could use a mask to hide the segments