# Smooth intersection between two paths without joining the paths

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I have two paths which intersect. I want to smooth the vertex where they intersect, but not join the lines so that their layers stay separate. Is there a way to do this?

My ultimate goal is to achieve the following animation: [Separately Animating Multiple Segments That Belong to One Layer: Adobe Illustrator and After Effects](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/140105/separately-animating-multiple-segments-that-belong-to-one-layer-adobe-illustrat?noredirect=1#comment209180_140105)

Comment: You should detail the why.. just copy/paste that comment explaining the animation to here. `:)` Sorry.. just trying to help.

Comment: Yes that is a good point. Thank you for the suggestion!